# Create a Twitter Poll with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, twitter

I am trying to find the code to create a twitter poll using google script while using a spreadsheet. I have the spreadsheet and most of the code, but am getting hung up on the params format that is need to do the poll.

Here is a sample of my code.

```
params = {entities: { 
        polls: [
  {
    options: [
      {
        position: 1,
        text: "I read documentation once."
      },
      {
        position: 2,
        text: "I read documentation twice."
      },
      {
        position: 3,
        text: "I read documentation over and over again."
      }
    ],
    end_datetime: "Mon Mar 23 12:20:00 +0000 2020",
    duration_minutes: 60
  }
]
      }
```

};

```
      var response;
      Logger.log(params);
      if (params) {
        params.muteHttpExceptions = false;
        response = getTwitterService().sendTweet(status, params);
      } else {
        response = getTwitterService().sendTweet(status);
      }

      if (response.hasOwnProperty("errors")) {
        throw (response.errors[0].message);
      }
```

Comment: There is no API for posting Twitter polls, so I'm not surprised that this does not work. What documentation are you following?

Comment: This is what I'm using.https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/entities-object

Comment: Those are read-only entities - there is no API for creating / posting Twitter polls.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its ready now:
[POST accounts/:account_id/cards/poll](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/creatives/api-reference/poll)

Create a new poll card associated with the specified account. This endpoint supports creating poll cards with either an image, a video, or no media. Polls with media are referred to as Media Forward Polls.

Note: The Media Forward Polls product is in beta and requires the PROMOTED_MEDIA_POLLS account feature.

Note: It is not possible to update (PUT) poll cards.

Resource URL
https://ads-api.twitter.com/10/accounts/:account_id/cards/poll